# Attempting to Install and Use PHP via GitBash

Tags: php, windows, bash

I've been struggling with getting php and gitbash to work together on my Windows 7 machine.

I went through the installing PHP for Windows Command Line following the steps on http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.commandline.php. I put it in C:\PHP and created environment variables for the 3 .exe files they suggested.

Now, I am doing all of this to attempt to get PHPMD to run. http://phpmd.org/download/index.html
However, when I trying to execute the line:

~ $ curl -s http://getcomposer.org/installer | php

I get a bash.exe": php: command not found.

From what I am reading this is due to environment variables but I am positive I have those setup correctly.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should only have to set *one* variable, namely `$PATH`. Which three did you set, how, and to what?

Comment: what happens if you just type "php" at your prompt?

Comment: @Biffen I set php.exe, php-win.exe php-cli.exe within $Path

Comment: @cjr `$PATH` should contain *directories*, not files. Read about it in `man bash`. Oh, and it's case-sensitive.

Comment: @Biffen Right! Thanks for point that out, though I still see the same error after fixing it to just be C:\PHP\

Comment: @cjr Since the filename is `php.exe` you'll probably have to use that instead of just `php`.

Comment: Windows programming is a nightmare and I guarantee this won't be your last problem getting something basic like this working =\

Answer (score 0):

My solution ended up being to install Ubuntu and do this all on linux. It is supremely easier to setup and use. I'd suggest anyone having issues with this to simple get Ubuntu and work from there.